# add reference System.Web.ApplicationServices to .net 4

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio 2013 and trying to add reference to System.Web.ApplicationServices. But when I check the box left to System.Web.ApplicationServices and click OK, then close the window, I still get an error saying

Reference required to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version =4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' containing the type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser'.Add one to your project.

And when I open the add reference window again, I see the box left to System.Web.ApplicationServices is still not checked. I see a related link 
[Switch from old ASP.NET Membership to ASP.NET identity (Visual Studio 2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178218/switch-from-old-asp-net-membership-to-asp-net-identity-visual-studio-2013)
but I don't know the solution for that?
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Are you trying to add ASP.Net Membership Provider?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this sounds like a Visual Studio issue more than anything else. Were you able to resolve it? If so, you may want to provide your solution as an answer and accept it to close this out.